# How to loop over every character of a filename?

Tags: bash, shell-script

So, I've a simple nested loop where the outer `for` loops over all the files in a directory and the inner `for` loops over all characters of these filenames.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
        echo "Please provide an argument"
        exit
fi

for file in `ls $1`
do
        for ch in $file
        do
                echo $ch
        done
done
```

The script above doesn't work. The inner loop doesn't loop over all the characters in the filename but instead loops over the entire thing.

UPDATE:

Based on @ilkkachu's answer I was able to come up with the following script and it works as expected. But I was curious can we not use the `for...in` loop to iterate over strings?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
        echo "Please provide an argument"
        exit
fi

for file in `ls $1`; do
        for ((i=0; i<${#file}; i++)); do
                printf "%q\n" "${file:i:1}"
        done
done
```

Comment: Never use `ls` to gather a list of files for scripted usage! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am new to this, could you please explain why this is bad and what should I do instead?

Comment: I added a link to my comment that explains that.

Comment: I would change "character" to "byte" in the title, since "character" isn't well defined without an encoding, and has multiple definitions if you're dealing with Unicode.

Comment: To add to Marcus Müller's comment, if you are entering the filename as an argument, why do you use ls anyway?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The answers to that question have some great stuff. The question is exceedingly long and confusing (I think the OP was editing it to argue with the answers?)

Comment: @Wastrel I don't wish to loop over the directory provided as an argument, but I want to loop over all the files inside that directory.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee again, don't use `ls` for that; that's bad. `for file in "$1"/*` just works.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it separately. And seriously, don't use `ls`. It isn't needed here and it just makes your script less likely to work. ilkkachu gave you a version without `ls`, so use that! For more details on why parsing `ls` is bad, see: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
word=foobar
for ((i=0; i < ${#word}; i++)); do
   printf "char: %q\n" "${word:i:1}" 
done
```

`${var:p:k}` gives *k* characters of `var` starting at position *p*, `${#var}` is the length of the contents of `var`. `printf %q` prints the output in an unambiguous format, so e.g. a newline shows as `$'\n'`.

Comment: +1, You `i` miss the `$` in the word expansion

Comment: @roaima Oh! Amanzig! God to know

Comment: @DanieleGrassini, the inside of a `for (( ))` and the index and offset in `${var:p:k}` are arithmetic contexts, and plain variable names without the `$` work there. Or you could do stuff like `${word:i+1:1}`. The `${#word}` needs the `${}` though, no way around that.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini more details at https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2004

Comment: +1, This is a really succinct and beginner friendly answer, I could achieve what I was looking for. But I had a question can we not use the `for..in` loop to iterate over strings?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee, no, you'd need to be able to split the string to individual elements somehow, and the shell can't do splitting between each and every character. `for x in $var` would word-split `$var` on the characters specified in `IFS`, but an empty `IFS` means no splitting, not splitting everywhere (unlike in Perl, where `split "", "abcd"` would split into characters). Also, since there are no 
real types, it's hard to tell a single-element list from a single word. Unlike in Python where `for i in "abcd":` is different from `for i in ["abcd"]:`.

Answer (score 8):

When the strings become larger than a few hundred characters (yes, unlikely for filenames), using a for-loop over the string length and extracting the character at index `i` becomes very slow.

This answer uses advanced bash techniques:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r -d "" -n 1 char; do
    # do something with char, like adding it to an array
    chars+=( "$char" )
done < <(printf '%s' "$string")

# inspect the array
declare -p chars
```

That uses a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to redirect the string into the while-read loop. I'm using `printf` to avoid adding a newline onto the end of the string. The main advantage of using a process substitution instead of `printf ... | while read ...` is the loop executes in the **current** shell, not a **sub**shell.

I once got curious about the magnitude of the slowness and [benchmarked it](https://github.com/glennj/exercism.io/blob/main/_mentor_notes/bash.md#performance-impact-of-string-length).

Comment: heh, funny, I wonder if it copies the whole string around with `${var:p:k}`. Ksh isn't any better there.

Comment: That `${#string}` is surprisingly slow makes me think bash is walking a linked list. But I haven't looked into the code at all.

Comment: not just `${#var}`, but the substring expansion too. For a 9999 char string, I got about 1.5 s for `for ((i=0; i < ${#word}; i++)); do : ${word:i:1} ; done`, 1.2 s with `${#word}` replaced with a constant var, and 0.08 s with the substring expansion removed in addition.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, even though the question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), an alternative that uses POSIX shell features only:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
for fname
do
  while [ "${#fname}" -ge 1 ]
  do
    rest=${fname#?} char=${fname%"$rest"} fname=$rest
    printf '%s\n' "$char"       # Do something with the current character
  done
done
```

What the inner loop does:

- set `rest` to the value of `fname` minus its first character;
- assign the single character obtained by removing `rest` from the end of `fname` to `char`;
- set `fname` to the value of `rest` and repeat until all characters are processed.

Note the quotes in `${fname%"$rest"}`, needed to prevent `$rest`'s expansion from being used as a pattern.

As an aside, `` for file in `ls $1` `` should be avoided. The most obvious reason is that it breaks if a file name contains any character that happens to be in `IFS`. More on this at [Bash Pitfall n. 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), including what you should do instead.

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for name do
    printf 'name="%s"\n' "$name"
    
    printf '%s\n' "$name" | fold -w 1 |
    while IFS= read -r character; do
        printf 'character="%s"\n' "$character"
    done
done
```

The outer loop here just loops over the arguments given to the script.  Each argument is printed as is, and then passed through `fold -w 1`, which creates a stream of single characters separated by newline characters.  This stream is then read by the inner loop, which prints each character in turn.

Testing:

```
$ sh script *
name="script"
character="s"
character="c"
character="r"
character="i"
character="p"
character="t"
```

```
$ sh script /*bin*
name="/bin"
character="/"
character="b"
character="i"
character="n"
name="/sbin"
character="/"
character="s"
character="b"
character="i"
character="n"
```

By changing the `printf` that prints the full pathnames into `fold` to `basename "$name"`, you get only the filename portion of the pathnames in the inner loop:

```
$ sh script /sbin/l*
name="/sbin/ldattach"
character="l"
character="d"
character="a"
character="t"
character="t"
character="a"
character="c"
character="h"
name="/sbin/ldconfig"
character="l"
character="d"
character="c"
character="o"
character="n"
character="f"
character="i"
character="g"
```

Comment: nitpick, `fold -w1` would break if the string contains newlines..

Answer (score 1):

Use the `bash` string slicing operator:

```
s="string"
for c in $(seq 0 $((${#s}-1)));  do echo "${s:c:1}"; done

s
t
r
i
n
g
```

Applied to your script can be:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do
    echo "Char in $f:"
    for i in $(seq 0 $((${#f}-1))); do
        echo "${f:i:1}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Loop over each filename** in the current directory “*" (can be easily customised for specific needs “~/*.jpg” etc…) and populate **string variable “ff”** with each character composing the current filename in the loop (“$ff" can also be understood as an array of single characters with ${ff:10:1} being the single 10th character in the ff “string array”). *Nota: if we wanted 2 characters rather from the 10th index we would write ${ff:10:2}*
2. **echo “➜ ${ff}”** simply to check current filename in the loop
3. Loop over the “string array ${ff}” to **echo each of its index values**, from first (bash variable starts at index **0**) to last (**#ff** gives total size of the array) - this is done by incrementing c by 1 (c++), from initial value of 0, and stop when it reaches #ff value
4. echo a **blank space** before shifting to the next filename

```
for ff in *; do 
  echo -e "--> $ff" ; 
  for ((c=0;c<${#ff};c++)); do echo -e "${ff:$c:1}"; done ; 
  echo -e ""; 
done
```

*Steps 2) and 4) (“echo” statements) are obviously for cosmetic purposes only and may be skipped.*

Comment: Apart from the outer loop, wouldn't that be the same as the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656965/377345)?

Comment: I guess you are not wrong, my bad! Bar aforementioned "outer loop” - as well as my irrepressible bias for the humble, if basic (sic!) **”echo”** command,vs. its more sophisticated, if less readable **“printf”** cousin.